# DynamicMenu extension for VS2019 loads the menu too late

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I have a VS extension with uses a Dynamic menu. So it uses a vsct to define some menu items on the Solution and the Project and then it loads sub-items dynamically. This extension works fine in VS2017 and many older versions.

Now I am updating it to work in VS2019. I have adjusted the target versions and I ran into an issue where VS2019 will not allow you to load packages synchronously, so I change my extension class to use AsyncPackage and InitializeAsync. And even with these changes, everything seems to work fine when I build and run this project for VS2017.

But in VS2019, the DynamicMenu is loaded too late. If I run Visual Studio 2019 and open a solution and then right-click on the Solution or project in solution explorer, the menu items defined in the vsct  are thre, but the DynamicMenuPackage hasn't been loaded yet, and so the sub-menu's are not yet populated and I end up seeing the placeholder sub-menu.

If I simply wait 30-60 seconds, it eventually loads. I can literally see that the static constructor for my DynamicMenuPackage : AsyncPackage gets hit eventually. But that's no good. I need to ensure that the menu is populated when the user opens it.

How can I do that when it's loading asynchronously?
I have tried every option for ProvideAutoLoad that I can find, including:

```
VSConstants.UICONTEXT.DesignMode_string
VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string
VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExistsAndFullyLoaded_string
```

But none of these produce reliable results.

Is there some way to use AsyncPackage and still somehow force it to load synchronously? Without, of course, turning on the 'Not-Recommended' Visual Studio option to load extension synchronously.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Please have a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-asyncpackage-to-load-vspackages-in-the-background?view=vs-2019).

Comment: I've read that page. That's how I got as far as I've gotten. But it make no mention of dynamic menus so it does not answer my question.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will search and investigate it. And if I have any progress, I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to load AsyncPackage synchronously. All we can do is to set

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string, PackageAutoLoadFlags.BackgroundLoad)]
```

and wait.

Comment: So how are you supposed to ensure that menus are loaded when the user expands the menu? There has to be some way to do that, doesn't there? Seems like a massive hole in extensions, otherwise.

Also... why does it work in VS2017 and not in VS2019? So weird.